# Travelling to Dubai on last date of tourist visa

Tags: visas, uae

I got a 30 day tourist visa issued from the UAE on 13th March and the document says valid until 11th June 2023. Is this until-date inclusive?

My flight is scheduled to land in Dubai on 11th June 9 PM? Will I be allowed to enter the country by immigration and stay there for 9 days after that?